# Need help with Values

Tags: php, web

I want to take a value
*ex:* `<input type="hidden" name="quicksearch" value="**1**" />`
from a third party website.

then place that value on my website
*ex:*  `<input type="hidden" name="quicksearch" value="**REPLACE WITH 1**" />`

Comment: Uhh you're going to have to be more specific than that..

Comment: sorry It's hard to explain... I am asking how to take one value from another website and place it on my own.
Could you contact me via AIM and I'll explain in more detail?
my aim is skiddie

Comment: No, explain in more detail on here. It sounds like you need to use Regex and some page downloader.

Comment: Okay I'm going to try to explain in detail...
Lets saying I'm viewing the source of www.google.com
it says <input type="hidden" name="search" value="1234" />

I want to grab that line of code and place it on my website like this
<b>Hello world</b>
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="1234" />

Comment: In that case, @webbiedave's post should do exactly what you need based on what information you have given us.

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.somepage.youwant/to.get');
$newHtml = preg_replace('!<input type="hidden" name="quicksearch" value="\*\*([0-9]+)\*\*" />!', '<input type="hidden" name="quicksearch" value="**REPLACE WITH \1**" />', $html);
```

[file_get_contents](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

[preg_replace](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

[Back references](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php)